# how to test with spring filter

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing

I have added a simple spring filter to my filter chain as follows:

> ```
> @Component("MDCRequestUniqueIdentifierServletFilter")
> public class MDCRequestUniqueIdentifierServletFilter extends DelegatingFilterProxy {
> @Autowired
> private UserRepository userRepository;
> @Override
> public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
>     try {
>         Integer newActivityCode = userRepository.getNewActivityCode();
>         MDC.put("ActivityCode", String.valueOf(newActivityCode));
>       } finally {
>           chain.doFilter(request, response);
>           MDC.remove("ActivityCode");
>       }
> }}
> ```

but now when i run my tests i get the following:

```
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ServletContext must not be null
```

because of that filter...

I have tried declaring it menualy on my test context but that did not help.
Tried adding stuff like:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
```

Didnt help as well.

Comment: have you done entry for this filter in web.xml also?

Comment: Yes, the problem is only when testing. not when running the server.

Comment: I Solved the problem by excluding the filter from my component scan. this is not a solution to the problem but it fixed it.